# How do I organise search results by date in outlook?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

When I type something into the search bar in the desktop client of Outlook 365 (Version 2002), I get some kind of random ordering of folders despite asking for the items to be organised by date:

[image]

How can I make outlook organise the result by received date?

**Edit**: John suggested that I could look at the "view" tab but I don't see anything there that might help:

[image]

Comment: Do you have the ability not group (View, Arrange by, Uncheck Show in Groups.  I also show Single Line (Change View Settings).  These two settings will help you.

Comment: @John I don't seem to see that option - see my screenshot that I've added to the question.

Comment: What version of Outlook are you using?  Perhaps add Arrangement in the Customize Ribbon Tab.

Comment: Also uncheck "Show in Conversations"  That groups things as well.

Comment: I saw your screenshots but cannot find random ordering? Are they not orderly?

Comment: @Aidan 9:41am shows up on top of 9:42am with descending date order selected.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem in Office 365 version 2008.

The source of the problem is the "top results" that Outlook uses to try to highlight what it thinks are the most relevant results, and it pushes them to the top without regard to the sort order you've requested. I can't guarantee this works for any other versions, but you can remove this "feature" in the current version with these steps:

Go to "Search Tools" in the ribbon, and click on "Search Options" in the dropdown menu:

[image]

In the menu that appears, uncheck the box that says "Show most relevant search results on top":

[image]

After following these steps, the "Top Results" section will be gone, and all results will be sorted in the order you requested:

[image]